# Understanding UnderScore.js when used Function Constructor

Tags: algorithm, underscore.js

at this moment, I learn how this chunked code of [underscore.js](https://code.google.com/p/polygonzo/source/browse/underscore.js?repo=static) flows,

```
 var render = new Function(settings.variable || 'obj', '_', source);
```

---

I liked to see how it understanded since compared with my example code, I can simply write it up.

```
 var render = new Function("a", "b", "return a + b");
```

then it will become,

```
 var render = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
 };
```

Can someone help me to describe how it flows please?? (sorry if My English bad.)

---

from the commentators, I'd like to asked, how `source` describe or flow as in my simple function, it summarize two parameters.

obviously, I can understood, that `source` should be consist of 
`a` as `settings.variable || 'obj'`
and 
`b` as `'_'`

but, I do not know, 
what kind of operator(s) which `run` in `source` part??

---

as I learnt my self, the truly problem is in `b` as `'_'`, may be I need a lot of time then, but this the complete chunked of codes that I talked about.

```
  // JavaScript micro-templating, similar to John Resig's implementation.
  // Underscore templating handles arbitrary delimiters, preserves whitespace,
  // and correctly escapes quotes within interpolated code.
  _.template = function(text, data, settings) {
    settings = _.defaults(settings || {}, _.templateSettings);

    // Compile the template source, taking care to escape characters that
    // cannot be included in a string literal and then unescape them in code
    // blocks.
    var source = "__p+='" + text
      .replace(escaper, function(match) {
        return '\\' + escapes[match];
      })
      .replace(settings.escape || noMatch, function(match, code) {
        return "'+\n_.escape(" + unescape(code) + ")+\n'";
      })
      .replace(settings.interpolate || noMatch, function(match, code) {
        return "'+\n(" + unescape(code) + ")+\n'";
      })
      .replace(settings.evaluate || noMatch, function(match, code) {
        return "';\n" + unescape(code) + "\n;__p+='";
      }) + "';\n";

    // If a variable is not specified, place data values in local scope.
    if (!settings.variable) source = 'with(obj||{}){\n' + source + '}\n';

    source = "var __p='';" +
      "var print=function(){__p+=Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, '')};"
      +"\n"+source + "return __p;\n";

    var render = new Function(settings.variable || 'obj', '_', source);
    if (data) return render(data, _);
    var template = function(data) {
      return render.call(this, data, _);
    };

    // Provide the compiled function source as a convenience for build time
    // precompilation.
    template.source = 'function(' + (settings.variable || 'obj') + '){\n' +
      source + '}';

    return template;
  };
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here. Your example is correct, and that's exactly what Underscore is doing in the code you include.

Comment: Do you know how [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) works or is that the question? Do you know how `_.template` works?

Comment: @muistooshort I don't know such things, I just know how simple `Function` works. I am new to javascript.. ^^

Comment: `_.template` converts the template to JavaScript source code and then hands that to `new Function` to produce a compiled version of the template as a function. I don't know if there's anything more to say than that.